# Local Development does not show record

Tags: lightning-web-components

Local Development server does not show record in LWC template. When I call apex method it returns  record and it visible in template but only when web component is pushed to org, in local development it is not visible

Comment: How are you attempting to access the record in your component? There are many unsupported features in local development, and the feature is currently in beta so there may be large bugs. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_local_dev_modules

Comment: I spent much time for resolving it, but below is my answer, I resolved it and after wrote this question. Maybe for somebody it will be helpfull. Thanks @nbrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when add @track decorator to record variable

Comment: @track decorator already does not necessary in lwc, but local development does not render records without it

Comment: Looks like you accidentally created a duplicate account?

Comment: @IgorVasylevskyi You can use the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page to have Stack Exchange staff merge your duplicate accounts.